# Healthy leaf fell off aloe vera plant. Looks like there may be some mold

Tags: diseases, aloe

I transplanted an aloe vera into a larger pot a couple months ago. I used cactus soil. Suddenly a leaf fell of it. The leaf had looked healthy and was green and plump. Upon looking closer I can see white balls of fluf closer to the stem, and what may be rot.

What is this? Is my plant unhealthy? What can I do about it? How often should I be watering it and how much? This is an indoor plant. What should I do with the leaf that fell off, I heard of freezing aloe and reusing it for sunburns (which aren't likely this time of year).
[image]
[image]
[image]