# What can be done with an aloe vera leaf that fell off and still looks healthy? Start a new plant?

Tags: houseplants, growth, aloe

I had asked [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/61222/healthy-leaf-fell-off-aloe-vera-plant-looks-like-there-may-be-some-mold) (with no replies) about a healthy looking leaf suddenly falling off an aloe vera.

I'm wondering what I could do with the leaf? It is still healthy looking and plump. I would like to start a new aloe plant in a different pot, but from what I red this is often unsuccessful when using a leaf. Is there anything else I can try? Anyway of preserving an aloe leaf for later use, for example I've heard of making ice cubes to apply to sun burns (but it's almost winter now).

From the look of the leaf, is there a fungus on the plant? I just re potted it with fresh dirt :(

[image]
[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1CaC.jpg)
I had put the fallen off leaf into a bag. I notice the liquid that evaporated into the bag is more of a brown color than like water.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stem-facing part is rotten. You can try to slice it off cleanly higher up and put the moist bit into soil, but there's no guarantees that it'll grow.

If you want to use the gel, cut it off where the leaf is fully healthy. Then slice it in half and scoop out the clear gel. It's great for the skin, and helps heal burns.

Answer (score 0):

I have one that I'm leaving on the kitchen counter so the end can dry out and restart roots by drying out so putting it in a bag keeps the end from drying out